# Definite integral with difficult term in the denominator.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I want to integrate $$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+R^2-2rR \cos(\phi)+(z-b)^2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+R^2-2rR \cos(\phi)+(z+b)^2}} d \phi.$$

You may assume that the denominator is not zero, as $z \neq b$. Furthermore, I think that even a series representation of the solution wuld be fine, so actually there is no restriction on the kind of solution I want to have as long as I get rid of this integral there.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn it to a complete elliptic integral of the first kind with $\phi=2\theta$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind

Comment: could you show me how to express it in terms of this function?

Comment: Develop $\cos{2\theta}$.

Comment: sorry, I mean how do you end up with this $K$ like integral there?

Comment: Don't you see the resemblance ? Don't forget that $r$, $R$, $z$ and $b$ are constants. Establish a term like $k_1+k_2\sin^2(\theta)$.

Comment: But there is also this problem that this integral there is from $0$ to $\frac{pi}{2}$ and not $\pi$ and frankly, I don't see through this. I mean, if it is that obvious, why can't you just write it down?

Comment: hi, are you still reading here? I really don't get there.

Comment: Sorry, I have no time/no will to solve this in your place.